# ajax.googleapis.com conflicts with joomla 3

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, joomla3.0

why ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js conflicts with joomla 3 ? and how can solved this problem?

I use google map and when I add ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js the map stop work and when I remove ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js the map work but joomla "tab" and "field sql" stop working

help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Joomla site is almost certainly already loading a (different) version of jQuery, so there's probably a conflict between versions.

> …the map work and joomla "tab" and "field sql" stop working

Field sql? Not even sure what you are referring to here, can you please explain. Tabs are probably Bootstrap versions, but that depends entirely on your template if you are referring to the front-end. Or are you talking about the tabs in the admin interface?